# How to match specific URL in JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to match the specific URL like "http://www.google.com" in JavaScript

```
var str = "http://wwww.google.com"
var test = match(str)
if(test) {
    alerT(match with the url)
}
```

Please suggest me how to do it.

Comment: What are some valid/invalid URLs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be `http` or `https`, so better to verify the URL in two steps:

```
  var str = "http://www.google.com";
  var protocol = str.match(/http/gi);
  if (protocol != null){
       var url = str.match(/wwww.google.com/gi);
       if(url != null){
                //Do your work
            }
       }
```

Comment: Please consider adding some text explaining your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test if the variable matches the specific url, you can use a simple expression.

```
var str = "http://wwww.google.com";

if(str == "http://wwww.google.com"){
  alert('string matches');
}
```

Comment: please add a description as to how this resolves the issue. [answer]